# xamarin android sending sms error exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

No errors, no warning, but when I clicked the send button it will return an error exception. please help me about this issue, this is the first time that I build an android messaging app.

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Java.Lang.SecurityException: Timeout exceeded getting exception
> details

MainActivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Telephony;
using System;
using Android;
using Android.Content;


namespace MhylesOrderingApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private SmsManager _smsManager;
        private BroadcastReceiver _smsSentBroadcastReceiver, _smsDeliveredBroadcastReceiver;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            var smsBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSend);
            var phoneNum = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.phoneNum);
            var sms = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtSMS);
            _smsManager = SmsManager.Default;

            smsBtn.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                var phone = phoneNum.Text;
                var message = sms.Text;

                var piSent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
                var piDelivered = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);

                _smsManager.SendTextMessage(phone, null, message, piSent, piDelivered);
            };
        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            _smsSentBroadcastReceiver = new SMSSentReceiver();
            _smsDeliveredBroadcastReceiver = new SMSDeliveredReceiver();

            RegisterReceiver(_smsSentBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
            RegisterReceiver(_smsDeliveredBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();

            UnregisterReceiver(_smsSentBroadcastReceiver);
            UnregisterReceiver(_smsDeliveredBroadcastReceiver);
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver]
    public class SMSSentReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            switch ((int)ResultCode)
            {
                case (int)Result.Ok:
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "SMS has been sent", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
                case (int)SmsResultError.GenericFailure:
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Generic Failure", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
                case (int)SmsResultError.NoService:
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "No Service", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
                case (int)SmsResultError.NullPdu:
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Null PDU", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
                case (int)SmsResultError.RadioOff:
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Radio Off", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    [BroadcastReceiver]
    public class SMSDeliveredReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            switch ((int)ResultCode)
            {
                case (int)Result.Ok:
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "SMS Delivered", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
                case (int)Result.Canceled:
                    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "SMS not delivered", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          package="MhylesOrderingApp.MhylesOrderingApp" 
          android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <application 
    android:allowBackup="true" 
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" 
    android:supportsRtl="true" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  </application>
</manifest>
```

activity_main.axml

```xml
<EditText 
        android:id="@+id/phoneNum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtSMS"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your error by using you code. And solved it by the following 2 steps:

1 Add the `Xamarin.Essentials` NuGet package to each project as follows:

In the Solution Explorer panel, right click on the solution name and select Manage NuGet Packages. Search for Xamarin.Essentials and install the package into your project.

[image]

2 Use RuntimePermissions for SendSMS after Android 6.0 version:

1) Modify the event of button click:

```
    smsBtn.Click += (s, e) =>
    {
        var phone = phoneNum.Text;
        var message = sms.Text;
        var piSent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
        var piDelivered = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);

        if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 23)
        {
            _smsManager.SendTextMessage(phone, null, message, piSent, piDelivered);
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.SendSms) != (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                // Permission is not granted. If necessary display rationale & request.
                RequestSendSMSPermission();
            }
            else
            {
                // We have permission, go ahead and send SMS.
                _smsManager.SendTextMessage(phone, null, message, piSent, piDelivered);
            }
        }
    };
```

2) Add the following function in the MainActivity class:

```
   public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }


    void RequestSendSMSPermission()
    {
        Log.Info("MainActivity", "CAMERA permission has NOT been granted. Requesting permission.");   
        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.Permission.SendSms))
        {
            Log.Info("MainActivity", "Displaying camera permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            Snackbar.Make(layout, "Camera permission is needed to show the camera preview.",
                Snackbar.LengthIndefinite).SetAction("OK", new Action<View>(delegate (View obj) {
                    ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.SendSms }, REQUEST_SENDSMS);
                })).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.SendSms }, REQUEST_SENDSMS);
        }
    }
```

3) Set the id property of the root of main layout:

```
android:id="@+id/sample_main_layout"
```

I have posted a demo to [github](https://github.com/lemontreexf123/so54901858test).